# Android send sms by intent.createChooser

Tags: android

This how I let the user send an sms:

```
Intent intentt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intentt.setType("text/plain");
intentt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
intentt.putExtra("address", selecteditem_phone);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentt, ""), 0);
```

This brings up a list of a lot of apps. How can I tell android to bring up only the sms capable apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your intent like this instead:

```
Intent intentt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);         
intentt.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
intentt.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
intentt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
intentt.putExtra("address", selecteditem_phone);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentt, ""), 0);
```

Comment: Good. This brings up a file explorer and quickoffice :)

Comment: Instead of intentt.setType("text/plain"); the solution was intentt.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

Comment: That is correct. I've edited my response to include this for canonical purposes.